# Scala. Need for loop where the iterations return a growing list

Tags: scala

I have a function that takes a value and returns a list of pairs, pairUp.

and a key set, flightPass.keys

I want to write a for loop that runs pairUp for each value of flightPass.keys, and returns a big list of all these returned values.

```
val result:List[(Int, Int)] = pairUp(flightPass.keys.toSeq(0)).toList
for (flight<- flightPass.keys.toSeq.drop(1))
{val result:List[(Int, Int)] = result ++ pairUp(flight).toList}
```

I've tried a few different variations on this, always getting the error:

```
<console>:23: error: forward reference extends over definition of value result
for (flight<- flightPass.keys.toSeq.drop(1)) {val result:List[(Int, Int)] = result ++ pairUp(flight).toList}
                                                                             ^
```

I feel like this should work in other languages, so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you've defined `result` as a `val`, which means it is immutable and can't be modified.

So if you want to apply "`pairUp` for each value of `flightPass.keys`", why not `map()`?

```
val result = flightPass.keys.map(pairUp)  //add .toList if needed
```

Comment: I think there may be a buffer limit of some sort. result.length has a value of 933, but flightPass.keys.length is longer. or is that not relevant?
This is why I started  messing around with horrible for loops

Comment: @MatthewIrwin, 933 isn't very big unless you're working on a small computer with limited memory. It's hard to solve a problem without an adequate description of the error. You could add `.toIterator` when extracting the keys. That way `result` will be an `Iterator`, which takes up very little memory. It will extract and process each key one-at-a-time and only when requested.

Comment: each pairUp returns a list with around 5000 entries. So the final result  would have around 5 million pairs of numbers in it post flattening

Comment: when I drop X amount from flightPass.keys, result.length also shrinks. So it might not be an error, just something odd

Comment: changing flightPass.keys to flightPass.keysIterator fixed it. Never needed that specifically before. The computer I use is reasonably beefy

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

A Scala method which converts a List of values into a List of Lists and then reduces them to a single List is called `flatMap` which is short for *map then flatten*. You would use it like this:

```
flightPass.keys.toSeq.flatMap(k => pairUp(k))
```

This will take each 'key' from `flightPass.keys` and pass it to `pairUp` (the mapping part), then take the resulting `List`s from each call to `pairUp` and 'flatten' them, resulting in a single joined list.